# React JS - Reload JavaScript files when component is reloaded

Tags: reactjs

I have a React JS app in which I am using Jquery DataTable to render a table. I have included the Jquery DataTable css and js files inside the public folder. When I load the page for the first time (the page refreshes in the browser) then the DataTable renders perfectly but if I navigate to another component and then come back to this component then it does not load the js files.

Loaded for the first time (the page refreshes in the browser):
[image]

Loaded when I navigate from another component:
[image]

So basically, the dataTable js file does not load when the component is re-rendered.

I tried to re-initialize the dataTable method inside the component but that does not work.

**app.js (this file has all custom js for the app):**

```
$(function () {
    initDataTable();
});

function initDataTable() {
    $('.js-basic-example').DataTable();
}
```

**index.html (this file has reference to the dataTable and above js files):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />

  <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/" />

  <title>React App</title>

  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.datatable.min.css">
</head>

<body class="theme-blush">
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

<script src="assets/js/datatable.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Users.js (this file has the dataTable):**

```
export const Users = () => {
    window.initDataTable();

    return (
        <section className="content">
            <div className="block-header">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <h2 className="pt-8">Users</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row clearfix">
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="header">
                                <h2><strong>All</strong> Users </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div className="body">
                                <div className="table-responsive">
                                    <table className="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Position</th>
                                                <th>Office</th>
                                                <th>Age</th>
                                                <th>Start date</th>
                                                <th>Salary</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Position</th>
                                                <th>Office</th>
                                                <th>Age</th>
                                                <th>Start date</th>
                                                <th>Salary</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                                <td>61</td>
                                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                <td>$320,800</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                                                <td>Accountant</td>
                                                <td>Tokyo</td>
                                                <td>63</td>
                                                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                                                <td>$170,750</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                                                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                                                <td>San Francisco</td>
                                                <td>66</td>
                                                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                                                <td>$86,000</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick fix -**
Please put window.initDataTable(); from Users.js file inside useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.initDataTable();
}, []);
```

you were running this function before the view was rendered. that's why it was not working.

**Better way to do -**
Better way to do add datatable, bootstrap in your project would be to add from react libraries.
eg.

- https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/getting-started/introduction
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component

Let me know if you have any questions.